# Base Pages in XAML Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have multiple user controls in XAML with shared code that I want to put in a base page so I want

```
singleLine.xaml --> singleLine.xaml.cs --- > basepage.cs

doubleLine.xaml --> doubleLine.xaml.cs --- > basepage.cs
```

singleLine.xaml

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="White">
  <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped"/>
  </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>  

  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0"  BackgroundColor="White">
        <Label x:Name="ViewTitle" Style="{StaticResource lblJobDetailName}" />
        <Label x:Name="ViewValue" Style="{StaticResource lblJobDetailValue}" />
    </StackLayout> 
  <Image x:Name="EditIcon" Source="edit.png" Margin="15,15,15,15" IsVisible="false" WidthRequest="15" HeightRequest="15" />
</StackLayout>
```

singleLine.xaml.cs

```
 using System;
 using Xamarin.Forms;

 namespace Client.UI.Pages.UserControls
 {
    public partial class SingleLine :   Client.UI.Pages.UserControls.BaseUserControl
    {  
        // do stuff


        #region Constructors 
        public SingleLine()
        {
              InitializeComponent();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

}

basepage.cs

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Xamarin.Forms;

  namespace Client.UI.Pages.UserControls
  {
     public class BaseUserControl: Xamarin.Forms.ContentView
     {
          public BaseUserControl()
          {
          }
     }
  }
```

The system wont compile and i get the following error

```
 Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'BaseUserControl' does not exist in the namespace 'Client.UI.Pages.UserControls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    Client.UI   C:\Projects\Client.UI\Pages\UserControls\SingleLineItem.xaml.cs 8   Active
```

This seems like a simple thing to do but is causing a headache, any ideas ?

Comment: your class is called SingleLine and the constructor is SingleLineItem? seems pretty weird to me

Comment: also your constructor is outside the  class.... in addition to the naming problem ...

Comment: oops made a mistake with the class definitions updated it now

Comment: No solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
 using System;
 using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Client.UI.Pages.UserControls
{
   public partial class SingleLine :   Client.UI.Pages.UserControls.BaseUserControl
   {  
    // do stuff
      #region Constructors 
      public SingleLine()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
      #endregion

  .... etc
  } // end of class
}
```

Also you do not need to explicitly declare the name space as both SingleLine and BaseUserControl are in the same namespace....

```
 public partical class SingleLine : BaseUserControl
```

This should work....

Comment: that is a close copy to what I have, my problem comes when the class  Client.UI.Pages.UserControls.BaseUserControl is not recognised ?

Comment: they are both using the same namespace